# Server purchase advice AMD Opteron

Tags: virtualization, 64-bit

- Dell PE2970 with AMD Opteron 6core 2431 2.4GHz + 64GB 667Mhz RAM - 2435 is not available with Dell now
- Dell R905 with AMD Opteron 8435 2.6 GHz + 64GB 800Mhz RAM - but this CPU is 4-8 way, I have chosen only 2P config

Both are very close on price and I am leaning towards the R905, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R805 is a dual socket AMD Server that supports the 24xx series six core CPU's and is more of a direct replacement than the R905.

Other than that the R905 is a newer generation of Dell Server and I would tend to go with that rather than the older 2970 in any case.

Comment: but R805 has only 600GB Max internal storage. Is it safe to go with r905 with 2P config and upgrade later to 4P. Does Dell allow later upgrades of CPU?

Comment: The price difference between similarly configured R905 and R805 is a couple of $k. If internal storage is the sticking point then the R905 does give you 5 internal 3.5" drive bays which will sort that out but that's a lot to pay just to get more internal bays. Do you specifically have to use AMD CPU's and Dell because if you are willing to look at Intel powered Server's Dell's 11G (R710) range is quite capable and can support up to 6 3.5" Drives for a similar price range to the R805 and HP's current generation servers tend to support even more internal drive bays.